# Validating @RequestParam using @Annotations

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I'm trying to validate @RequestParam of my parameter. Here's my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addCategory", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addCategory(@ValidCategoryName @RequestParam(value = "categoryName") String categoryName) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

    boolean addedSuccessfully = sideViewControllerDelegate.addMenuCategory(categoryName);

    modelAndView.setViewName("home_partial/side_view/category_completed");
    if (addedSuccessfully) {
        modelAndView.addObject("responseMessage", "ADDED");
    }
    return modelAndView;
}
```

And The @ValidCaegoryName is defined like this:

```
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, PARAMETER})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@NotNull
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValidCategoryImpl.class)
public @interface ValidCategoryName {
        String message() default "This Category Does not Seem to Allowed";

        Class<?>[] groups() default { };

        Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };

        int min() default 30;
}
```

And my Impl class is this:

```
public class ValidCategoryImpl implements ConstraintValidator<ValidCategoryName, String> {

    @Autowired
    MenuCategoriesService menuCategoriesService;

    private int min;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidCategoryName constraintAnnotation){
        min = constraintAnnotation.min();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String categoryName, ConstraintValidatorContext context){
        return categoryName.length() < min && menuCategoriesService.containsCategoryName(categoryName);
    }
}
```

Am i Missing anything?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find this pattern in any guide or tutorial? What makes you think that Spring would invoke your validator?

Comment: I've seen similar pattern used at work for validation for similar use cases.

Comment: On a `@RequestParam`?

Comment: I've tried on @RequestParam and then i tried in different layers too, like my service layer, but it's still not working. It just seems like I'm missing something in my .xml bean configuration, cause this validation isn't getting invoked.

Comment: What I found so far that in my class (for now I have it in my service class) I have '@Validated' for my interface, and within for my "addMenuCategory" I have '@ValidCategory', which from what I'm seeing spring should recognize...but It's not